# Save and Close redirect

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, administrator, custom-action

I'm modifying the administrator panel in Joomla and when a user press "Save and close" in the edit module i want it to redirect to `/administrator`, not `/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules`.

Is this posible? I have searched in `/administrator/includes and administrator/components/mod_modules/module/view.php`, and have found where the class is and where it is executed, but no luck yet.

My understanding for PHP is small, so keep it simple.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, may I ask?

Comment: Iam using Joomla for a infoscreen for a customer. I have made a custom controlpanel in the backend for him with a specifik ACL. I want to keep him on the frontpage of the backend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `ROOT/administrator/components/com_modules/controllers/module.php`, and edit at about line 223 (right after `parent::save($key, $urlVar);`, and before the closing `}`)

```
$this->setredirect('index.php');
```

**Disclaimer: This is a core hack, and not recommended. Your changes will be lost when you update Joomla.**

Comment: Thanks alot! I worked fine. Is it posible to copy the code and creating a new .php file that is loaded. So i dont lose the code when update?